# How to make my azure django project https?

Tags: django, azure, https

I have my website in Azure named

> djangoproj.azurewebsites.net

When I request homepage it goes to **http**://djangoproj.azurewebsites.net. I know all projects in azure are SSL protected and when i type **https**://djangoproj.azurewebsites.net, it works fine ! I can access the site via https. But how do i make it to default https in azure?  because when i call the homepage, it gives **http** response by default until i **forcibly** specify **https**.

How do i make default https in azurewebsite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` will redirect all traffic to https when set to `True`.

[Relevent section in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/security/#ssl-https)

Comment: even if i set that, it does not work. Can i test it locally in my local computer before pushing it to azure ? I checked pushing to azure and locally in both ways, it doesn't redirect me to https

Comment: The `./manage.py runserver` command does not support https, so testing it locally is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config (for example, web.3.4.config in your repository root), append the following rule to the rules section:

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I have this in production on a django 1.9 app on Azure App service.